# Getting a JSP name from within the servlet (or a servlet filter)

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlets, request

I have a bunch of JSP pages all of which are managed by a single servlet. I tried getting a JSP page name using the request's method getRequestURI for getting a full JSP path, but it returns only the path to the servlet (without any JSP page). Is there a way to retreive a JSP name from the HttpServletRequest? Thanks.

In case when I have in url:

```
 http://localhost:8080/TutorWebApp/page/common/login.jsp
```

I want to get on servlet with help request /page/common/login.jsp

Comment: Could you show some URLs used with your application?

Comment: @EmmanuelBourg I made a note above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HttpServletRequest#getRequestURL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29)?

If you get a url of the jsp, you can write the following in the jsp file.

```
<%= request.getRequestURL() %>
```

Comment: you can request.getRequestURL() in get/post method.
It's the same way any servlet

Comment: When I use this func() I get url : /TutorWebApp/controller not url jsp

Comment: What is the relationship between controller and jsp? I think if you know it better.For example, What if you have relationship like AbcServlet = abc.jsp?